# Apply style to element, only if a certain element exists next to it

Tags: html, css

I'm using the `<section>` tag on several pages, but on ONE page I'm using an `<aside>` tag that is preceded by the `<section>` tag.

In the case that I have a `<section>` immediately followed by an `<aside>`, I would like to apply a width to both and have the section float left, and the aside float right.

Basically, if I have a `<section>` and `<aside>` I want the style to work like this:

```
section {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

aside {
    padding:8px; 
    width:400px;
    float:right;
}
```

If I only have the `<section>` I want it to be like:

```
section {
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Is there a way I can do this with either a conditional statement in CSS3, or a pseudo-class, without having to use JavaScript, custom classes, or separate CSS files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This only works if the `<section/>` comes after the `<aside/>`:

```
<aside>content</aside>
<!-- if there is another node in between, use the '~' selector -->
<section>content</section>
```

In that case you could use `aside ~ section` or `aside + section`:

```
section {
    padding: 8px;
}
aside + section {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}
```

In all other cases you'll have to use JavaScript because these selectors only work in one direction, top to bottom.

<del>With CSS4 there might be a way using the [Subject of a selector with Child combinator](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/subject-of-selector-with-child-combinator/), but that's future.</del> This selector was removed from the specification.